# Adjusting the DIV event segments that hold the events and not an event "resize"

Tags: fullcalendar

### Quick Background:

- I am making a Paid Time Off (PTO) calendar for several regions in the US.
- I am using Zend framework, jquery, fullcalendar, Expand/All by www.adipalaz.com, and a custom "more..." link
- I have 3 different jquery tabs with a new instance of a calendar on each tab (level 1)
- Each tab has a different topic related to the PTO, with 3 accordion sections
- One accordion section per tab has a filter to filter the results on the calendar
- One accordion section per tab has a calendar on it (level 2)
- The first calendar pulls from two different Event sources through a JSON call/feed
- This calendar pulls PTO according to region
- The regions are displayed as an all day event
- Each "event" is an Expand/Collapse using www.adipalaz.com (level 3)
- When each "event" is expanded or collapsed using the www.adipalaz.com an AJAX call pulls all the PTO related to that region
- Each expanded AJAX call hides details about the extra info unless the custom "more..." link is clicked (level 4)
- Each custom more link also has some actions (level 5)

Now, all of the above works.

I have a .click function which handles "level 3" and above.  Part of this .click function is the AJAX call and another part gets and sets the z-index so that my "level 4" data pops above all the other non-expanded "level 3" data.
So far, that functionality is fine.  The problem is all my underlying data still needs to be visible.

### My multi-tiered problem

1. rerender all the events on the calendar so that the week and events are all visible regardless of the clicked "level 3"
2. once rerendered not losing the "level 3" .click action which disappears if I use the $('#calendar1').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents'); and not losing the "level 3" data that was displayed prior to trying to rerender the event.

I have images visually explaining my question but am unable to upload them due to this being my first post.  If you have an idea how to help me and need to see the pictures just let me know.

Currently this is all I have towards this problem:

```
//POPS THE OPEN ITEM UP IN Z-INDEX
$(uniqueID).parent().parent().css('z-index',9);

//THIS FINDS OUT WHAT TO ADD
changeSizeOfDiv = $(uniqueID).next('.fc-event-names').html(data).outerHeight()
     + $('.fc-week' + level + ' .fc-sun').outerHeight();

//THIS ALTERS THE ROW SIZE
$('tr.fc-week' + level).css('height',changeSizeOfDiv);
```

I still haven't figured out how to dynamically update the following row "top: #px;" after clicking on a region.  I think just pushing the top down by using the changeSizeOfDiv function should work but as of right now I have no idea how to do this, let alone do this elegantly.

Any ideas would be welcome.
Thanks

Comment: To clearify your propblem you can use a picture service ( eg tinypic.com ) or a code playground like jsfiddle.net. Provide your pictures in an edit of your post, so we can better understand the task.

Answer (score 0):

So with a lot of help this is what I came up with and it works like a charm.  I added this to the calendar initialization

```
eventClick: function(event, element) {
    if (typeof event.originalTitle == 'undefined') {
        event.originalTitle = event.title;        
    }

    if (event.loaded) {
        event.title = event.originalTitle;
        event.loaded = false;
        $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: regionNamesUrl + getFilterUrlPart(event.segmentDate,event.region),
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){                                
                event.title = event.originalTitle + '<br/><br/>' +data;
                event.loaded = true;

                $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);

                clicker(event,'approved');
                clicker(event,'cancelled');
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('An error has occurred retrieving data from the server.  Try reloading the page.');
            }
      });
    }                
}
```